# Why do 2>&1 (redirect stderr to stdout) with <&- >&- 2>&- (close stdin, stdout, stderr)?

Tags: io-redirection

Why would someone do this

```
(exec <&- >&- 2>&-; gzip somefile.txt) 2>&1 &
```

<&- >&- 2>&- "...means close stdin, stdout and stderr, respectively.."

but why do "2>&1" if it's closed?

Answer (score 3):

The statement mentioned is incorrect because the standard file descriptors must be open.

[POSIX specification:  C.2.7 Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html)

> Applications should not use the `[n]<&-` or `[n]>&-` operators to execute a utility or application with file descriptor `0` not open for reading or with file descriptor `1` or `2` not open for writing, as this might cause the executed program (or shell built-in) to misbehave. In order not to pass on these file descriptors to an executed utility or application, applications should not just close them but should reopen them on, for example, `/dev/null`. Some implementations may reopen them automatically, but applications should not rely on this being done.

The instruction would rather be

```
gzip somefile.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to do what they did. The `2>&1` is indeed completely redundant in that example.